# How to make a List serializable for RPC?

Tags: java, gwt, serialization

I have a `List<Foo> foos` which I can send to a `GWT RPC service` without problems.
But if I wrap that list into a new object, I'm getting an exception on startup.

```
subtype MyDTO is not assignable to 'com.google.gwt.user.client.rpc.IsSerializable' or 'java.io.Serializable' nor does it have a custom field serializer (reached via MyDTO)
```

Why can I send the list itself, but not a wrapper object?

with:

```
class MyDTO {
    List<Foo> foos; //containing Rectanlges (see below)
    public MyDTO() {}

    List<Foo> getFoos() { return foos; }
    void setFoos(List<Foo> foots) { this.foos = foos; }
}
```

with Foo beeing an interface like:

```
interface Foo {
    abstract int getX();
    abstract void setX(int x);
}

class Rectangle implements Foo {
    private int x;
    public Rectangle() {};

    //impl of foo methods
}
```

Of course this structure does not make much sence, but it describes my problem.
If I just send the List foos via RPC everything works fine.

If I send the MyDTO wrapper holding the list of foos, mentioned Exception is thrown.
What is wrong here?

Comment: is your myDTO class extends Serializable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make MyDTO implement `Serializable`. `List` is Serializable by default.

Comment: It isn't. It's standard implementations (e.g. `ArrayList`) are serializable.

Comment: I meant Whatever he is passing as a List by List. Of course List cannot implement Serializable. It is an interface.

Comment: Great this was a quick fix. Implementing Serializable let the app compile.

Comment: Of course `List` can be `Serializable`. It's called interface inheritance. So all implementing classes have to be `Serializable`, too.